# CreateQueryBuilder does not return data with oracle because typeorm generates sql in lowercase and quotation marks

Tags: oracle, typescript, orm, typeorm

I'm trying to make a small query to an Oracle using `createQueryBuilder` but it doesn't return records.

I have noticed that TypeORM generates SQL in lowercase and with quotes (like this: `SELECT "m"."codigo" AS "m_codigo", "m"."descripcion" AS "m_descripcion" FROM "moneda" "Moneda", "moneda" "m"`) and this is what is generating the problem in oracle because when I remove the quotes or ... I convert the query to uppercase, it returns data.

code:

```js
import { EntityRepository, getRepository, Repository , Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Moneda {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    codigo?:      number;

    @Column()
    descripcion?: string; 

    @Column()
    simbolo?:     string;

    @Column()
    decimales?:   number;   

}

@EntityRepository(Moneda)
export class MonedaRepository extends Repository<Moneda> {

    constructor() { super() }

    async getListaMonedas(){

        return await getRepository(Moneda).createQueryBuilder()
            .select( ["m.codigo", "m.descripcion"] )
            .from( Moneda, "m" )
            .getMany();
    }
}

//in another file...

    import { MonedaRepository } from "./store";
    const monedaRepository = new MonedaRepository();
    const monedas = await monedaRepository.getListaMonedas();
   console.log(monedas);

// result:   [ ]
```

Comment: Really? I was using `this.repository.createQueryBuilder("alias")
            .select(["alias.ID","ANOTHER_FIELD"])
            .where("alias.ID = :id", { id: idparam })
            .getOne();` and it generate the following query: `SELECT "alias"."ID" AS "alias_ID", ANOTHER_FIELD FROM "tablename" "alias" WHERE "alias"."ID" = :idparam`. Doing fine.

Comment: in oracle?
do not you indicate the clause "from ..."?

Comment: Yes in oracle. I don't since I have it declared in the entity (`@Entity("TABLE_NAME")`. And import the entity as a repository like `@InjectRepository(Reponame) private readonly Repoalias: Repository<Reponame>` but it shouldn't matter. https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-repository

Comment: thanks, that's the solution !! :-D
additionally to make it work, instead of getMany () getRawMany () must be used

Comment: You can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was given to me by @Mukyuu.
You must indicate the name of the entity in Entity ("TABLE") written in capital letters, and in the querybuilder instead of getMany () ... getRowMany () ... (the name of the columns must be capitalized as well) :

```js
const result = await getRepository (Currency) .createQueryBuilder ("M")
       .select (["M.CODIGO", "M.DESCRIPCION"])
       .getRawMany ();
```

This worked for me.

Comment: it's a shame all the viable solutions defeat the purpose of an ORM in the first place: having "sql dialect"-agnostic code... As of 2022, I'm still facing that same issue. I'm yet to find a Typescript-based solution to handle this elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Oracle identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) are case-insensitive. You can make them case-sensitive by using quotes around them.

Wrap your column names with single quote without any aliases e.g.

```
const result = await getRepository(Currency)
   .createQueryBuilder()
   .select(['"CODIGO"', '"DESCRIPCION"'])
   .getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own naming strategy:

```
export class OracleNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {
  tableName(targetName: string, userSpecifiedName: string): string {
    if (userSpecifiedName) return userSpecifiedName;

    return super.tableName(targetName, userSpecifiedName).toUpperCase();
  }
  columnName(
    propertyName: string,
    customName: string,
    embeddedPrefixes: string[],
  ): string {
    if (customName) return customName;
    return super.columnName(propertyName, null, embeddedPrefixes).toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

and use it:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'oracle',
      ...
      namingStrategy: new OracleNamingStrategy(),
      ...
    })
```